# What is the difference between 'any, light, dark' appearances in Xcode assets

Tags: ios, xcode

There are 3 options, light and dark I get, why is there an any? is it for backwards compatibility? Thanks!

Comment: Yep! If the device is iOS 12 or before, `Any` will be used.

Comment: Although, you can just do Any + Dark (no need for light). Light mode in iOS 13 will continue to just use Any, and so will devices with iOS 12 and below.

Comment: it's weird that we can't choose Light + Dark (without Any) for apps supporting iOS 14+

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances):

> Light and dark appearances. Provide images for both light and dark appearances. Use the Any Appearance slots to support older versions of macOS or iOS.